# Can large datasets be used with Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, bigdata, excel-2013

I've been reading in several places that [Excel 2013 (64-bit) has the ability to open larger datasets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/whats-new-in-powerpivot-in-excel-2013-HA102893837.aspx#_Toc335818198), with more rows than before. Yet, my limits seem to be right at where they were with 2010.

I get the same old error about having more than a million or so rows. I was just curious if anyone was able to get larger data sets to import/open. If so, any steps that you went through might be helpful to all. I've tried on 4 different 64-bit Office 2013 PCs and have had no luck.

Comment: Excel can not handle big data. Hope Microsoft has to come with something when it comes to handling Millions of records.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The row limit in Excel 2013 is still 1 million except for Pivot Tables and PowerPivot: the only thing 64-bit Excel gives you is the ability to use more than 2 Gigabytes of memory.

Comment: +1 for memory. Sure all the rest is true.

Answer (score 3):

The row limit in Excel 2013 is still 1,048,576 ( x 16,384 columns). The article you are linking refers to data size, not amount of rows.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers already show, the limit in the worksheets itself have not changed, it's still 1M rows.

What has changed is the amount of data you can handle in Powerpivot. This data can be read into the Powerpivot cache - and modified/extended with the DAX formulas - and aggregated with the pivot tables. However, you cannot "edit" them, as you can with normal Excel data.

Before you were limited by the 2GB/4GB barrier - which already allowed for multiple million rows depending on your dataset. With Excel 2013, this limit is now gone - the only restriction is your machines memory. However, you can still not edit the raw data, only handle (DAX) and aggregate (pivot tables) them!

Comment: Have you had luck with larger datasets (+2gb) in PowerPivot? I'm still getting the same old errors there as well. PowerPivot is what I was using with 2010.